# See changes on page without updating

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

How can I update content on my page without refreshing it? Is there a specific code for it? When I register a customer he/she is registered in a table and in a option value, when I delete the customer he/she will only be removed from the table but not from the option unless i refresh the page.

These are my delete function

```
function slett(kundeselkey){

    var slettkunde = kunde.child(kundeselkey);
    slettkunde.remove();
    var tr = document.getElementById(`${kundeselkey}`);
    txttabell.removeChild(tr);
}

function slette(mekselkey){
    var slettmekaniker = mekaniker.child(mekselkey);
    slettmekaniker.remove();
    var tr = document.getElementById(`${mekselkey}`);
    txttabell3.removeChild(tr);

}
```

Comment: You are looking for Ajax

Comment: hmm, i dont know what that is, but i will check it out thanks :)

Comment: Seems to me that you're updating the content, since the customer is removed from the table. What do you mean by "but not from the option"? What option?

Comment: when i register a customer he/she is registered in a select option and in a table, the table value gets deleted properly but the select option is still there untill i refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you can use `.on()` method to listen to a change in your Firebase node.

So every time an item is added, deleted or updated in your database the code you add inside `.on()` method will be triggered.

This way you can handle the options and table values dynamically

Example:

```
firebase.database().ref('your-node').on('value', (snapshot) => {
  const updatedValues = snapshot.val();
  const optionList = document.querySelector('#yourSelectId').options;
  updatedValues.forEach(option =>
    optionList.add(
      new Option(option.text, option.value, option.selected) // considering your firebase node item contains text, value and selected attributes
    )
  );
});
```

You can find more details here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Hope it helps